# Conditional alignment of text inside html paragraph

Tags: php, html-table

Here is table data that sometimes needs to be aligned right, and other times needs to be aligned center:

```
<td colspan="5"><p align="right"><?php echo number_format($total_adjusted_taxes,2) ?></p></td>
```

What determines whether to align right or centered is this variable:

```
<?php $r_or_c = (count($categories)==1?"right":"left");    
?>
```

What is the best way to use this variable `$r_or_c` inside the p tag?

Comment: I'd suggest removing the `p` tag entirely, and using `<td style="text-align: <?php echo $r_or_c; ?>;">`. That, or assign a class-name to the `td` ('right' or 'center'), and use that to style the text-alignment.

Comment: Thanks David.  This was indeed was I was looking for.  Worked perfect.

Comment: I've posted the above comment as an answer, in response to your own comment.

Comment: "Perfect" is an adjective. "Perfectly" is the adverb for which you are looking.

Answer (score 0):

I'll write something like this. You're going to echo in place the correct value:

```
<p align="<?php echo count($categories)=='1' ? 'right' : 'left'; ?>">....</p>
```

I prefer using CSS to style elements, though, so you can use the same method to assign a different class, or just `style="text-align:<?php echo....;?>">`. Using class is better because you won't need to make changes in every single paragraph you write your inline style.

If you define your variable somewhere else, and just want to echo it (like your doing, it seems):

```
$r_or_c = count($categories)=='1' ? "right" : "left";

<p align="<?php echo $r_or_c;?>">....</p>
```

As someone else said, it's better not to use this inline styling, or you'll make your code more difficult to maintain in the future. You could style the `<td>` instead of your paragraph also:

css:

```
  .left { text-align:left;}
  .right { text-align:right;}
 /* OR : */
 td.left {}
 td.right{}
```

html:

```
<td class="<?php echo $r_or_c;?>">......</td>
```

Also, you said "center" but wrote "left", don't know what you really need, so in case just subsitute 'left' with 'center', obviusly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td colspan="5"><p align="<?php echo (count($categories)==1?"right":"left");?>"><?php echo number_format($total_adjusted_taxes,2) ?></p></td>
```

Is that what you asked?

Answer (score 0):

Just shove it in there. Not much complication to it.

```
<td colspan="5"><p align="<?=$r_or_c?>"><?php echo number_format($total_adjusted_taxes,2) ?></p></td>
```

On a side note, you should start using CSS for styling :)

```
.align-right { text-align: right; }
.align-left { text-align: left; }
```

-

```
<td colspan="5"><p class="align-<?=$r_or_c?>"><?php echo number_format($total_adjusted_taxes,2) ?></p></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

As my comment to the question, as responded to by the OP:

> ...was indeed [what] [he] was looking for. Worked perfect[ly].

I've opted to post that comment as an answer:

I'd suggest removing the `p` tag entirely, and using `<td style="text-align: <?php echo $r_or_c; ?>;">`. That, or assign a class-name to the `td` ('right' or 'center'), and use that to style the `text-alignment`.

Comment: We can see that you opted to post it as an answer. No need for the self-congratulatory preamble, I think.

Comment: It wasn't intended as self-congratulatory; just an explanation as to why my comment's now also an answer. My apologies if I offended you, somehow. Oh, and thank you for the edits.

Comment: I didn't think that it was intentional; just saying how it might come across. :) I don't see where "offending" anybody comes into it, but I realise that everybody's paranoid of that nowadays.